# Como iterar sobre grupos de un dataframe

Tags: pandas, bucles, dataframe, iteradores

Quería saber si se puede, y como se hace, un loop sobre grupos de un dataframe de Pandas. Tengo un archivo de texto, que lo importo con Pandas:

```
file= ("E:\Test.txt")
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', dtype='str')
df
```

Esto me da la siguiente informacion:

```
      Fecha      ID   Alum Par  Nombre  Codigo  Descrip Cantidad    Tiempo
0   09/03/2021  A935    809 00  CARMEN  660192  Hard Disk   1   2
1   09/03/2021  A935    809 00  CARMEN  660412  Floppy  25  1.5
2   09/03/2021  A935    809 00  CARMEN  660475  SSD 1   3
3   09/03/2021  A217    800 00  CONCEPCION  661070  DVD 1   15
4   09/03/2021  A217    800 00  CONCEPCION  662734  CD  3   36
5   09/03/2021  A218    801 00  ELVIRA  660192  Hard Disk   1   2
6   09/03/2021  A232    909 16  LORENZO 660343  Ata Disk    1   2
7   09/03/2021  A232    909 16  LORENZO 660475  SSD 1   3
```

siendo la primera columna el índice.

Dado que me intersa agruparlo por ID, aplico el siguiente código:

```
gb = df.groupby(['ID'])
for k, gp in gb:
   print ('key=' + str(k))
   print (gp)
```

con lo que llego a los grupos que me interesa, y que me sirve para poder ver cuantas filas tiene cada 'ID'. El resulado es el siguiente

```
key=A217
        Fecha    ID  Alum Par    Nombre  Codigo Descrip Cantidad Tiempo
3  09/03/2021  A217   800  00  CONCEPCION  661070     DVD        1     15
4  09/03/2021  A217   800  00  CONCEPCION  662734      CD        3     36
key=A218
        Fecha    ID Socio Par  Nombre  Codigo    Descrip Cantidad Tiempo
5  09/03/2021  A218   801  00  ELVIRA  660192  Hard Disk        1      2
key=A232
        Fecha    ID Socio Par   Nombre  Codigo   Descrip Cantidad Tiempo
6  09/03/2021  A232   909  16  LORENZO  660343  Ata Disk        1      2
7  09/03/2021  A232   909  16  LORENZO  660475       SSD        1      3
key=A935
        Fecha    ID Socio Par  Nombre  Codigo    Descrip Cantidad Tiempo
0  09/03/2021  A935   809  00  CARMEN  660192  Hard Disk        1      2
1  09/03/2021  A935   809  00  CARMEN  660412     Floppy       25    1.5
2  09/03/2021  A935   809  00  CARMEN  660475        SSD        1      3
```

Mi consulta es como puedo iterar dentro de los grupos para poder llegar a tener esta informacion mas facil de ver para cada grupo (ID):

```
   Resumen
   El 'Alum', 'Nombre', tiene 'Cantidad' de 'Descrip'.
   Fin
```

Donde tendría que tener 1 línea por línea del grupo. Hay forma de iterar dentro de cada grupo en Pandas? Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No está del todo claro lo que preguntas, pues parece que quieres obtener una línea en la salida por cada una de las filas de cada grupo, pero si es así no se entiende muy bien para qué los agrupas antes...

En todo caso, la cosa sería como sigue. Preparamos una función que recibirá una fila (ya sea del grupo o del dataframe original) y que retornará una cadena con el "resumen" que pides:

```
def resume_fila(fila):
  return "El {}, {} tiene {} {}".format(
      fila.Alum, fila.Nombre, fila.Cantidad, fila.Descrip
  )
```

Ahora tenemos varias formas de aplicar esta función:

#### 1) Iterando por filas de `df`

Con ayuda de `.iterrows()` sobre el dataframe completo:

```
for idx, fila in df.iterrows():
  print(resume_fila(fila))
```

Sale:

```
El 809, CARMEN tiene 1 Hard Disk
El 809, CARMEN tiene 25 Floppy
El 809, CARMEN tiene 1 SSD
El 800, CONCEPCION tiene 1 DVD
El 800, CONCEPCION tiene 3 CD
El 801, ELVIRA tiene 1 Hard Disk
El 909, LORENZO tiene 1 Ata Disk
El 909, LORENZO tiene 1 SSD
```

#### 2) Iterando por filas en cada grupo

Es decir, iterando por grupos y luego por filas del grupo:

```
for k, gp in gb:
  for idx, fila in gp.iterrows():
    print(resume_fila(fila))
```

El resultado es exactamente el mismo, aunque tal vez con los grupos en otro orden. Por eso no entiendo bien para qué agrupas antes.

#### 3) Usando `.apply()`

En lugar de iterar, usamos `df.apply()` para que aplique nuestra funcion a cada fila. El resultado será otro dataframe con una sola columna cuyos contenidos serán las cadenas "resumen":

```
df.apply(resume_fila, axis=1)
```

Resultado:

```
0    El 809, CARMEN tiene 1 Hard Disk
1      El 809, CARMEN tiene 25 Floppy
2          El 809, CARMEN tiene 1 SSD
3      El 800, CONCEPCION tiene 1 DVD
4       El 800, CONCEPCION tiene 3 CD
5    El 801, ELVIRA tiene 1 Hard Disk
6    El 909, LORENZO tiene 1 Ata Disk
7         El 909, LORENZO tiene 1 SSD
```

## Ampliación

Otro enfoque, en el que tendría más sentido la creación previa de grupos, podría ser el resumir *cada grupo* en una sola línea, que podría ser por ejemplo:

```
El 800, CONCEPCION tiene 15 DVD 1 y 3 CD
```

En este caso necesitamos una función que pueda recibir la columna Cantidad y la columna Descrip, en las que puede haber varios elementos, y a partir de ellos sintetice la cadena de texto "15 DVD y 3 CD", por ejemplo. Queremos que si solo hay un elemento retorne una cadena tal que así: "15 DVD", pero si hay dos los separe por "y", y si hay más de dos separe los primeros por coma y el último por "y".

Esta función haría eso:

```
def enumerar_items(cant, desc):
  items = list(zip(cant, desc))
  items_str = ", ".join("{} {}".format(cant, desc) for cant, desc in items[:-1])
  if len(items)>1:
    items_str+= " y "
  items_str += "{} {}".format(*items[-1])
  return items_str
```

Ahora podemos hacer uso de ella mientras iteramos por los grupos:

```
for k, gp in gb:
  alum = gp.Alum.iloc[0]
  nombre = gp.Nombre.iloc[0]
  items = enumerar_items(gp.Cantidad, gp.Descrip)
  print("El {}, {} tiene {}".format(alum, nombre, items))
```

Y la salida sería:

```
El 800, CONCEPCION tiene 1 DVD y 3 CD
El 801, ELVIRA tiene 1 Hard Disk
El 909, LORENZO tiene 1 Ata Disk y 1 SSD
El 809, CARMEN tiene 1 Hard Disk, 25 Floppy y 1 SSD
```

Comment: Hola Abufalia, por suerte no fui claro en mi pregunta, pero tu respuesta es fabulosa!
En realidad habia hecho los grupos en un momento para ponerle Resumen abajo los datos del grupo,  y luego Fin. Y con eso mandar un archivo de cada Alum. Pero la explicacion que me diste es super! Yo trataba de aplica el iterrows y el itterbucles y no habia podido llegar a tu solucion, siempre tenia errores.

Comment: Hola @abulafia, una consulta comp uedo hacer para poner un titulo entre Cada grupo en el caso 1 o 2, estuve tratando pero me pone un titulo para cada linea, no para cada grupo. Use ```df.keys``` para tratar de separar en frupos pero no hubo caso.. Gracias

Comment: En el caso 1) no es posible separar por grupos porque no se han hecho grupos. En el caso 2) sí se puede. El bucle  `for k, gp in gb:` va iterando por los grupos. En `k` tienes la clave que sirvió para agrupar ese grupo, por lo que puedes hacer `print(k)` o similar antes de pasar a iterar dentro del grupo.

Comment: Gracias, lo estuve haciendo todo el tiempo, pero en el lugar equivocado y no me salia el resultado que esperaba, ahora estoy trabajando en la salida elegante para cada alumno.... Gracias!!

Comment: Aca paso la solucion

```
for k, gp in gb:
  print('Resumen' + '\n' + 'Elementos')
  for idx, fila in gp.iterrows():
    print(resume_fila(fila))
  
  print('FIN')
```

Gracias!